# WCS Unable to render RenderedOp

Tags: geoserver, image, file-formats, tomcat, wcs

I have a GeoServer running with Tomcat, which serves GeoTIFF files as WMS, and it runs fine.

Now I am trying to set WCS.  It works with `plain/text` and `application/gml-xml` formats, but `image/jpeg` and `image/png` throw

> java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.

although they are supposed to be supported, as advertised by `GetCapabilities` :

```
<wcs:ServiceMetadata>
  <wcs:formatSupported>application/gml+xml</wcs:formatSupported>
  <wcs:formatSupported>application/x-gzip</wcs:formatSupported>
  <wcs:formatSupported>image/jpeg</wcs:formatSupported>
  <wcs:formatSupported>image/png</wcs:formatSupported>
  <wcs:formatSupported>image/tiff</wcs:formatSupported>
  <wcs:formatSupported>text/plain</wcs:formatSupported> 
…
```

Is there a missing library or something ?

Trimmed GeoServer logs ([full logs](https://pastebin.pl/view/b1898912)) :

```
2020-10-07 09:39:18,929 INFO [geoserver.wcs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2020-10-07 09:39:18,930 INFO [wcs2_0.util] -  Examining encoded name myLayer
2020-10-07 09:39:18,930 INFO [wcs2_0.util] -  Checking coverage name myLayer
2020-10-07 09:39:18,931 INFO [wcs2_0.util] -  - Collecting layer slope_4_grade
2020-10-07 09:39:18,952 INFO [geoserver.wcs] - 
Request: getCoverage
    extension:
    service = WCS
    version = 2.0.1
    baseUrl = https://example.org/geoserver/
    coverageId = myLayer
    dimensionSubsetGroup[0] = wcs:dimensionSubset=net.opengis.wcs20.impl.DimensionTrimTypeImpl@3db7fc0c (dimension: X, cRS: null) (trimLow: 3740000, trimHigh: 3750000)dimensionSubsetGroup[0] = wcs:dimensionSubset=net.opengis.wcs20.impl.DimensionTrimTypeImpl@5eeb704c (dimension: Y, cRS: null) (trimLow: 2500000, trimHigh: 2600000)
    dimensionSubset[0]:
        dimension = X
        trimLow = 3740000
        trimHigh = 3750000dimensionSubset[0]:
        dimension = Y
        trimLow = 2500000
        trimHigh = 2600000
    format = image/jpeg
2020-10-07 09:39:18,953 WARN [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream could not be aborted in time. An error has occurred and could not be sent to the user.
2020-10-07 09:39:18,953 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:827)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
[…]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-10-07 09:39:18,954 WARN [geoserver.ows] - OWS20SEH: handling org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
2020-10-07 09:39:18,999 WARN [geoserver.wcs] - Failed to fully dispose coverage: GridCoverage2D["slope_4_grade", GeneralEnvelope[(3740000.0, 2500000.0), (3750000.0, 2600000.0)], DefaultProjectedCRS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe"]]
�   RenderedSampleDimension("GRAY_INDEX":[-32767.0 ... -32767.0])
�     ? Category("No data":[-32767.0 ... -32767.0])
+ Image=RenderedOp["Mosaic"]

java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:827)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp$1.getPropertyNames(RenderedOp.java:1791)
[…]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-10-07 09:39:19,000 WARN [geoserver.wcs] - Failed to fully dispose coverage: GridCoverage2D["slope_4_grade", GeneralEnvelope[(3740000.0, 2500000.0), (3750000.0, 2600000.0)], DefaultProjectedCRS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe"]]
�   RenderedSampleDimension("GRAY_INDEX":[-32767.0 ... -32767.0])
�     ? Category("No data":[-32767.0 ... -32767.0])
+ Image=RenderedOp["Mosaic"]

java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:827)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getMinX(RenderedOp.java:2161)
[…]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-10-07 09:39:31,430 WARN [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - Cannot save page with id '7' because the data file cannot be opened.
```

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: @IanTurton Most messages seem relevant, so I only trimmed the stack traces.